# @Autowired class members declared with <default> scope instead of private

Tags: java, spring

I keep reading articles and tutorials on the Internet, that involve Spring, and I see that a lot of them have code samples where they declare their @Autowired members with scope ***default*** instead of **private**.

E.g.

```
@Autowired
AccountRepository accountRepository;
```

instead of

```
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;
```

I was wondering why that is. Because from a good encapsulation point of view I think this is wrong. Is there any benefit from doing this in Spring that I do not know of?

Comment: They can be private, but then spring has to change the visibility of the field via reflection; this may be disallowed by the security manager.

Comment: For real encapsulation, you wouldn't autowire fields. You would autowire the constructor instead. That also makes testing easier,a nd makes the dependencies clearer.

Comment: When giving an example, 'private' may be omitted just for brevity. They are not teaching you encapsulation in those tutorials, after all, and they want their main point to be as clear as it can be.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy that's what I thought too. I just wanted to make sure that I haven't missed something.

Answer (score 1):

It is never a good practice to inject the dependencies directly through fields, rather use the constructor injection (which @JBNizet pointed out as well), you can look [here](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/) for more details on this.

In short, you should be using `@Autowired` on the bean constructors which will generally be `public`.